# How to show that $ (1+|x|)^{-M}$ is lebesgue integrable for M>n?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Is it true that $(1+|x|)^{-M}$ is lebesgue integrable for M>n over $R^n$ and if so how can we prove it?

It seems like the theoretical definition for Lebesgue integral which is the sup of all simple functions would not help us here, but that might be one way to prove that $f$ is not integrable for M<n. To actually prove it is integrable, the easiest way seems to be to find another integrable function $g$ where $f\leq g$ but I don't have any in mind.

Comment: This is proved by polar coordinates.

Comment: @user1046533 , thx, i just tried the polar substitution and it works. A question I have is, when I do the polar substitution and carry out the integral, is that still considered integrable in the lebesgue sense or is that just considered an improper integral?

Comment: When you have a nonnegative function, the two notions are the same.

Comment: @user1046533 got it